# Javascript timer/counter crashing browser

Tags: javascript, setinterval

This code is meant to start a timer when you type something into the text input, that will count every second until it reaches 5 seconds, and then stop. But it keeps spitting out `0` which is creating an endless `while loop` that crashes the browser. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here :-/ !?

```js
var secondsPassed = 0;

function setTimer() {
  
  while (secondsPassed <= 5) {
    console.log(secondsPassed);
    setInterval(function() { secondsPassed += 1; }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="setTimer()">
```

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't block. so you are creating millions of timers

Comment: consider using async-await with a `sleep`

Comment: @DanielA.White a `sleep()`?

Comment: It is not crashing the browser, you just run into an endless loop.

Comment: I would like to update your code using setTimeout instead https://jsfiddle.net/n4jhrs95/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop will never stop because its condition (`secondsPassed <= 5`) will never evaluate to true, since `setInterval` isn't synchronous.

You should instead move the condition inside the `setInterval`.

```js
var secondsPassed = 0;

function setTimer() {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (++secondsPassed == 5) clearInterval(interval);
    console.log(secondsPassed)
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="setTimer()">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the wrong way to both set the interval and count time.

I recommend something on the lines of:

```js
var secondsPassed = 0, timerOn = false;
function setTimer(){
   if(timerOn) return;
   var t0 = Date.now();
   timerOn = true;
   var intervalId = setInterval(
       function(){ 
          secondsPassed = Math.round((Date.now()-t0)/1000);
          console.log(secondsPassed)
          if(secondsPassed >= 10){
              clearInterval(intervalId);
              timerOn = false;
          }
       }, 1000
   );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="setTimer()">
```

I stopped the timer after 10 seconds, for the case someone wants to test it, but of course, you'll have to stop it otherwise.